# Selenium How To Get Title Text?

Tags: c#, selenium, gettext

```
<span class="Voting__button Voting__button-up">
<a href="#" title="Upvote">  ---> Need get title word in my textbox
```

I tried it like this:

```
      textbox1.text= driver.findelement(by.xpath("//*[@id='posts_list']/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/span[1]/span/span/a")).Text;
```

I want to get this title but it’s not working.

Comment: Please add some information on what you did expext to happen and what happened instead.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you supplied **`C#`** tag, the `method()` is not `findelement()` but **`FindElement()`**.

So, as per the `HTML` you have provided to extract the `title` value **`Upvote`** you can use the following line of code :

```
textbox1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='posts_list']//span[@class='Voting__button Voting__button-up']/a")).GetAttribute("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Selenium` `getAttribute` method to get title word. 
Try using the below `XPATh`:

**Java code:**

```
textbox1.text = driver.findelement(By.xpath("//*[@id='posts_list']//*[contains(@class,'Voting__button-up')]/a")).getAttribute("title");
```

**C# code:**

```
textbox1.text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='posts_list']//*[contains(@class,'Voting__button-up')]/a")).GetAttribute("title");
```